# save ID on each item in loop so it can be used as a hyperlink, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating items in list from the below code. In order for it to display correctly I need to create an html string. Each item in this list is supposed to become a hyperlink where you click on it and it reloads the page with new data, so I need to save the ID on each item in order to retrieve the correct data for that item
What is the best way for me to do what I am trying to accomplish?

```
$(r.campuses).each(function(index, item) {
  if (item.campusID != 55) {
    var HTMLcontent = '<div class="ml-32 mt-16 mb"><a class="other-school"><label class="other-schools-list">' +
      item.campusName + '</label></a><br /></div>';
    $('.group').append(HTMLcontent);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need but looks like you want to put the `item.campusID` in the `href` attribute of your `a` element.

### UPDATE

Adding click listener to the code to handle user clicking on the link.

you can do it like this:

```
$(r.campuses).each(function(index, item) {
  if (item.campusID != 55) {
    var HTMLcontent = '<div class="ml-32 mt-16 mb"><a href="path/to/your/' + item.campusID + '" class="other-school"><label class="other-schools-list">' + item.campusName + '</label></a><br /></div>';
    $(HTMLcontent).on('click', function() {
      window.location.href = window.location.href + "?id=" + item.campusID;
    });
    $('.group').append(HTMLcontent);
  }
});
```

Just change `path/to/your/` to your correct path.

Comment: W.R. that worked thank you! I want to reload the current JS page that i am on. The page calls a fetch function with a URL that i will supply a dynamic ID based on what the user clicks from this list. Whats the correct href link I should put in? Or should i be using something like location.reload();
or   window.location.href = window.location.href + "?id"? Any suggestions?

Comment: if you just want to reload the current page use location.reload(); or if you want to point the user to the page with the ID which they clicked on use window.location.href = window.location.href + "?id=" + itemID (itemID is the variable)

Comment: I want the second option, send the users to the page with the ID they clicked on. How would i combine window.location.href = window.location.href + "?id=" + itemID with the code you suggested in this post?

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming if I have the window.location.href that I don't need the href with the campusID in the html string, correct?

Comment: Yes, right now since there's a click listener handling clicks, you don't need the "href" part anymore. It should be OK to just remove it from the HTML String. If this answer was helpful you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: OK thank you! I marked it as helpful. But being that I am new to SO it won't allow me to mark it off as the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190244/discussion-between-webrookie-and-r-p).